# Clear all fields on page with submit

Tags: javascript

[My code](http://plnkr.co/edit/SgkLADYEPD9QUTvekFB0?p=preview)

I am trying to clear fields after submit. I have tried everything I seen on google search nothing is working

```
<input type="text" id="a1">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit" onclick="w001()">
    <span id="a21"></span>
</form>

function w001() {
  var a = document.getElementById("1");
  if ((a.value == "a 7") || (a.value == "7")) {
    document.getElementById('a21').innerHTML = 'correct';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('a21').innerHTML = 'incorrect';
  }
`function w001Field() {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    document.a1.value = "";
  }
}
`}
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.a1.value = "";` is not valid.

use `document.getElementById("a21").value = ''`
or

Just `a.value = ''` because you've defined your input element on `var a = document.getElementById("a21");`

Final code

```
function w001() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a21");
    if ((a.value == "a 7") || (a.value == "7")) {
        document.getElementById('answera21').innerHTML = 'correct';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('answera21').innerHTML = 'incorrect';
    }
    a.value = '' // reset value of input with id a21
}
```

Comment: @KazTee works well here -> http://plnkr.co/edit/zcoNyS3sgPfY6pYTpBcl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

this id:

```
var a = document.getElementById("1");
```

does not exist

it should be

```
var a = document.getElementById("a1");
```

this function;

> w001Field()

Is never used

Change the code to

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" id="a1">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit" onclick="w001()">
    <span id="a21"></span>
</form>

    function w001() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a1");

    document.getElementById('a21').innerHTML = ((a.value == "a 7") || (a.value == "7")) ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';

    document.getElementById("a1").value = "";
}
```